# Action Button and Isolate seem to not work as expected in Shiny

Tags: r, button, plot, shiny

I've got a Shiny app that makes a plot according to user selection. As I only want a new plot after action button is selected, I've put plotting code inside "isolate". The result is that a new plot appears as soon as the action button is pressed, but sometime it also appears also without pressing on the button. In particular when I select subcategorized parameters that appears via a conditional panel ("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma",...). In the original version also changing the date may cause the plot to be re-executed. Here's my code: what am I missing?

```
callingColorPlot <- function(var) {
  listaMia<- list("alpha" = 2, "beta" = 3, "gamma" = 4, "delta" = 5, "epsilon" = 6, "zeta" = 7, "eta" = 8)
  valori <- (c(1:8))*10
  require(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Title"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel (position = "left", 
                      helpText(h4("Specificy:")), br(),       
                      selectInput("selectedColor", label = (strong("Select your color")), 
                                  choices = list( "Yellow selection", "Orange selection", "Blue selection", "Gray selection"), selected = ""),
                      conditionalPanel (
                        condition = "input.selectedColor == 'Yellow selection'",
                        selectInput("subCategory", label = (strong("Select sub categories")), choices = listaMia, selected="")
                      ),  
                      conditionalPanel (
                        condition = "input.selectedColor == 'Blue selection'",
                        checkboxGroupInput("letterCheckbox", label = strong("Select your letter"), 
                                           choices = listaMia, selected = "")
                      ), 
                      br(),
                      dateRangeInput("dates", label = (strong("Time Interval")), start='2012-01-02', end='2012-10-31', min='2012-01-02', max='2012-10-31'), 
                      sliderInput("sliderBegin", label = strong("Starting hour"), min = 0, max = 23, value = 0),
                      uiOutput("sliderInput"),
                      br(), actionButton("okButton", "Go")
        ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("plotResult")))  
    ), 
    server = function(input, output, session) 
      {
      output$sliderInput <- renderUI ({
        sliderInput("sliderFinal", label = strong("Final hour"), min = 0, max = 24, value = 24);           
      })     
      output$plotResult <- renderPlot ( {
        input$okButton
        if (input$okButton == 0)
        return()              
         isolate ({ 
           plotWidth=c(430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430)
           plotNames=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "Tot")
          if (input$selectedColor == 'Yellow selection') { 
            color='yellow'
            xlabel="Yellow selection"
            mainTitle="Yellow selection"
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Orange selection') {
            color='orange'
            xlabel="Orange selection"
            mainTitle="Orange selection"  
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Blue selection') {              
            if (length(input$letterCheckbox)==0)
              return()
            color='darkblue'
            xlabel="Blue selection"
            mainTitle="Blue selection"
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Gray selection') {      
            color='darkgray'
            xlabel="Gray selection"
            mainTitle="Gray selection"
          } 
          mychart <- barplot (valori, col = color, border='white'
                              , width=plotWidth, space=0.2
                              , xlab=xlabel, ylab="values", names.arg=plotNames
                              , ylim=c(0, 100), xlim=c(150, 3750), main=mainTitle)  
        }) 
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me and the button behaves normally. Check your reactive expressions (you said that you have date which is reactive) and put the input$okButton in there too (or put your date reactive into the isolate you have), so it will only re-evaluate expression when pressed.

Comment: Thanks for testing and commenting. I tested this code again, but the unwanted features is still there. Shortly If I plot any graph, than I change the color to "Yellow selection" or "Blue selection" and select one of more of the subcategories (greek letters), the plot changes also without pressing the action button. This happens just sometimes, but you should be able to replicate playing on this.

Comment: I am playing around with it now for 5 mins, and it works fine for me. (Im on shiny version 0.11.1 and R 3.1.2).

Comment: I just updated shiny version to 0.11.1 and now it seems to work fine (I was using version 10.2.2). Thanks for you support!

Comment: Now I've got a different problem on the dateRangeInput, as there's no more control if the time range is positive or not (I can select a final day earlier than the begin day, but this can cause some problems).

Comment: why don't you sub this into there (      output$sliderInput <- renderUI ({
        sliderInput("sliderFinal", label = strong("Final hour"), min = input$sliderBegin, max = 24, value = 24);           
      }))

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to what I've done in my original code. The problem is not on the sliderInput but in the dateRangeInput. Before updating Shiny packages the system automatically checked for a non negative time interval (in days). Now it seems to not do it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So coming back to your question overall:

1) You needed to update Shiny to most recent version, so that solved the problem with the button

2) Sliderinputs now in synch and the time will be set to 24 hours

3) I added the observe statement to control the `DateRangeInput` that would control the negative date range

```
callingColorPlot <- function(var) {
  listaMia<- list("alpha" = 2, "beta" = 3, "gamma" = 4, "delta" = 5, "epsilon" = 6, "zeta" = 7, "eta" = 8)
  valori <- (c(1:8))*10
  require(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Title"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel (position = "left", 
                      helpText(h4("Specificy:")), br(),       
                      selectInput("selectedColor", label = (strong("Select your color")), 
                                  choices = list( "Yellow selection", "Orange selection", "Blue selection", "Gray selection"), selected = ""),
                      conditionalPanel (
                        condition = "input.selectedColor == 'Yellow selection'",
                        selectInput("subCategory", label = (strong("Select sub categories")), choices = listaMia, selected="")
                      ),  
                      conditionalPanel (
                        condition = "input.selectedColor == 'Blue selection'",
                        checkboxGroupInput("letterCheckbox", label = strong("Select your letter"), 
                                           choices = listaMia, selected = "")
                      ), 
                      br(),
                      dateRangeInput("dates", label = (strong("Time Interval")), start='2012-01-02', end='2012-10-31', min='2012-01-02', max='2012-10-31'), 
                      sliderInput("sliderBegin", label = strong("Starting hour"), min = 0, max = 23, value = 0),
                      uiOutput("sliderInput"),
                      br(), actionButton("okButton", "Go")
        ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("plotResult")))  
    ), 
    server = function(input, output, session) 
    {

      observe({
        if(input$dates[1] > input$dates[2])
        {
          date1 <- input$dates[1]
          updateDateRangeInput(session, "dates", label = (paste("Time Interval")), start=date1, end=date1, min='2012-01-02', max='2012-10-31') 
        }
      })

      output$sliderInput <- renderUI ({
        sliderInput("sliderFinal", label = strong("Final hour"), min = input$sliderBegin, max = 24, value = 24);           
      })    
      output$plotResult <- renderPlot ( {
        input$okButton
        if (input$okButton == 0)
          return()              
        isolate ({ 
          plotWidth=c(430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430, 430)
          plotNames=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "Tot")
          if (input$selectedColor == 'Yellow selection') { 
            color='yellow'
            xlabel="Yellow selection"
            mainTitle="Yellow selection"
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Orange selection') {
            color='orange'
            xlabel="Orange selection"
            mainTitle="Orange selection"  
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Blue selection') {              
            if (length(input$letterCheckbox)==0)
              return()
            color='darkblue'
            xlabel="Blue selection"
            mainTitle="Blue selection"
          }else if (input$selectedColor == 'Gray selection') {      
            color='darkgray'
            xlabel="Gray selection"
            mainTitle="Gray selection"
          } 
          mychart <- barplot (valori, col = color, border='white'
                              , width=plotWidth, space=0.2
                              , xlab=xlabel, ylab="values", names.arg=plotNames
                              , ylim=c(0, 100), xlim=c(150, 3750), main=mainTitle)  
        }) 
      })
    })
} 

callingColorPlot()
```

Comment: Thanks. This way it works properly. I was astonished that this control was implemented in the previous version of shiny but not in the last.